# NFC with Google Wallet

Tags: mobile, nfc, android-pay

I came to know about mobile payment, I have Google Wallet with NFC support phone, Now I should develop Merchant machine, What should be the msg send to Google Wallet app via NFC to make mechant's payment done.?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just send a message to do a payment. That would be much to easy to abuse and everyone would build their own 'Merchant Machine' to make money out of nothing.

If you're interested how NFC payment works in general start reading here:

https://www.emvco.com/

Comment: Ya I know all the architecture, bla bla and the contactless communication. I went through more than 5 PDF of 40 pages. You miss understand my question I guess. Only the 'Merchant Machine' is not enough to pay the money, Google Wallet application need to be get the Merchant information in order to make the transaction. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXdkTGCwVYY

Comment: See this vdo. You have merchant machine. I need to develop that. Thats what I'm asking. For that Mechant machine sends merchant's ID to the Google Wallet for initiate transaction.